# SPSS Compute a new variable with the last four digits of a numeric variable

Tags: spss

I have a numeric variable (year of birth) in SPSS and i would like to take the last for digits out of it. Most values are like 1988, 2001, 1948 etc. But about 250 respondents entered their year of birth like 30-2-1947, or 2-9-1984 etc. That means not all values have the same length. By taking the last 4 digits into a new variable I could create an age category for all the respondents.

How can I do that?

I tried by converting the variable to a string and using `substr` to get a part of the value, but I always had to choose a starting point. I want to start from the last digit and then move backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `SUBSTR()` you can try using `RIGHT()` to grab the last four digits.

```
* convert yob to string variable.
ALTER TYPE yob (A10).
EXE .

* use RIGHT to extract the last 4 digits and convert to numeric.
COMPUTE n_yob = NUMBER(RIGHT(yob, 4, F4)) .
EXE .
```

You can now use `n_yob` to calcuate age (ex: `COMPUTE age = 2022-n_yob .`).  You can also use `ALTER_TYPE` again if you want to convert `yob` back to it's original type.